# Python: Tkinter text widget, new window button

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

I'm making a tkinter based text widget and I'm trying to implement a new window function in it. But every time I click on the new window button I get this error in IDLE : RuntimeError: Calling Tcl from different appartment

Here's my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Tkinter import *
from tkSimpleDialog import askstring
from tkFileDialog   import asksaveasfilename
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from tkMessageBox import askokcancel
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk 
import threading
from ScrolledText import ScrolledText
Window = Tk() 
Window.title("TekstEDIT")

/..CODE.../

class newWindowThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, choosen=""):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.choosen = choosen
    def run(self):
        if self.choosen == "":
            root = Tk()
            newEditor = SimpleEditor(root)
            root.mainloop()
        else:
            root = Tk()
            newEditor = SimpleEditor(root, self.choosen)
            root.mainloop()
/...CODE.../
wFile = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0,relief="raised")
    wFile.add_command(label="New", accelerator="Ctrl+N", command=self.onNew)
    wFile.add_command(label="New Window", accelerator="Ctrl+Shift+N", command=self.onNewWindow)
/...CODE.../
def onNewWindow(self):
    t=newWindowThread()
    t.start()
```

What's the source of the problem? How can I solve it?

Source Code: http://ideone.com/npWuYD

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix Tkinter and threading in this way. Tkinter isn't thread-safe. Also, tkinter is designed such that you should only ever have a single instance of `Tk` running.

If you want multiple windows, you don't need threads and you don't need multiple instances of `Tk`. Create your root window as usual, and for other windows create an instance of `Toplevel`.